# iPhone English (US) keyboard doesn't appear anymore after pasting a bitmoji

Tags: iphone

I have 3 keyboards in my keyboard list:

- English (US)
- Emoji
- Bitmoji

I was sending a message on the twitter app last night and I switched keyboards to bitmoji, selected one, and pasted it into the message box, and sent it. After that, I was unable to get back to the English keyboard.

From the bitmoji keyboard I see a "globe" icon and click it. This takes me to the emoji keyboard where I can then see the "ABC" icon and click it. This takes me to the bitmoji keyboard. I can't see a way to get back to the English (US) keyboard.

I've tried rebooting. I've tried closing all apps. How do I fix this?

Comment: If you hold down the globe key, don't you see a list of keyboards where you can choose English?

Comment: That seems to only happen when you’re already on the English keyboard (which magically just started working again as I was responding to this)

Comment: Maybe long-pressing the world icon made it come back? Not sure... weird

Comment: 3rd party keyboards can sometimes cause problems like that.